# Zend framework 2 navigation error

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2

I get a zend 2 navigation error, and can't seem to find a solution for it. Searched everything, tried everything.....

Here is my configs :

route `(Application/config/module.config.php)` :

```
'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

factory `(Application/config/module.config.php)` :

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',

        ),
```

navigation `(Application/config/module.config.php)` :

```
'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(

            array(
                'label' => 'home',
                'route' => 'home', 
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

layout `(Application\view\layout\layout.phtml)` :

```
 <?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend\Navigation\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid argument: $route must be a non-empty string or null' in 
/var/www/html/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 904
```

and

```
Zend\Navigation\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid argument: $route must be a non-empty string or null in /var/www/html/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Navigation/Page/Mvc.php on line 397
```

previous exception:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while
 creating "navigation"; no instance returned in /var/www/html/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 904
```

What is the problem? I cannot seem to get it working,...

Comment: Your configuration looks fine here; Although the error says you are passing `null` as the `route` value to to the `Mvc` class somewhere. Keep in mind that if you have any other navigation configuration in other modules (in `module.config.php`) that will also be included in the factory during bootstrap.

Comment: This was it! I had a navigation in one module....please post this as an answer so I can choose you!

Comment: I now have another error when trying to merge multiple navigation configs from different modules : Invalid argument: Unable to determine class to instantiate' ...any ideas?

Comment: I forgot that pages need double arrays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine here; Although the error says you are passing `null` as the route value to to the `Mvc` class somewhere.

Keep in mind that if you have any other navigation configuration in other modules (in `module.config.php`) that will also be included in the factory during bootstrap.

> I now have another error when trying to merge multiple navigation configs from different modules : **Invalid argument: Unable to determine class to instantiate**

The error is due to the navigation factory not knowing if it should create either a `Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc` or `Zend\Navigation\Page\Uri`. This means you are missing some configuration entries in your "navigation" config in `module.config.php`.

To make sure the factory can create the correct one you will need to ensure the following

- *URI pages* - Need `uri` key
- *MVC page*  - Need either a `route` key or one (or both) `controller` and `action` keys

You can read more about this in the [navigation documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.pages.html).